# Passing data from the Redux store, as Props, to an unknown number of routes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Here is the situation:

- I am getting an unknown amount of data from a service and putting it in my Redux store
- Each data-point will have its own route `/:rid`
- The route is setup like this `<Route path=':rid' component={Restaurant}/>` using react-router (v3) -- see full render method below
- I'd like to be able to pass the correspond data about the specific restaurant, the one whose route was navigated to, to the Restaurant component as props so it can render the component with the correct information for that restaurant

Right now my solution is to pass all the restaurants from the store into the Restaurant component as props `this.props.restaurants`. Then in `componentWillReceiveProps` I loop over all the restaurants in `this.props.restaurants` and check to see if the `rid` of each restaurant is equal to the `this.props.routeParams` ie `:rid`. If it is I then set that state to contain the data I want to show and reference `this.state.name` as opposed to the data being on `this.props.name'

Is there another way to do this? Right now it's not a performance issue but I can imagine looping over and arbitrarily large data set could lead to so serious load times. Also, it just seems like there should be a way for react-router to pass in this data as props so I can keep this component stateless.

Ideally, something like this would happen:

- a request is made to `/1234`
- react-router in my index.js consults/queries the redux store and finds the data for the restaurant with rid 1234 and passes it as props to the component it renders
- I imagine it looking something like this `<Route path=':rid' component={<Restaurant {...matchedRestaurant} />}/>`

Perhaps this questioning can be asked in short like, how do I make a unknown number of routes such that when one is navigated to it is rendered with the data for that corresponding restaurant as props?

Restaurant.js:

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.props.restaurants.forEach((restaurant) => {
        if(restaurant.rid == nextProps.routeParams.rid) this.setState({name: restaurant.name})
    })
}`

index.js:

`render(
    (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path='/' component={App}>
                    <IndexRoute component={RestaurantList} />
                    <Route path=':rid' component={Restaurant}/>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    ),
    document.getElementById('root')
)`

https://github.com/caseysiebel/corner-team/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: Wait, does your loop obtain a multiple amount of restaurants with the :rid equaling the route params? or is the :rid always unique?

Comment: Also, I think if you're iterating over a large amount of data in your component, you should instead start normalizing your data so that you can obtain data straight from your store by :rid, making it easier.

Comment: I'm assuming that all the rid's are unique.

The real question I'm having is how can I get react-router to pass the data from a single restaurant (the correct one) in the store to the Restaurant component it renders as props?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having react-router figure this out for you, you should be using selectors (and potentially a package like reselect). Reselect even has a section on how to base your selector on props (in this case like the routerParams.rid): https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors

For the non-Reselect solution, you could simply change the connect in your Restaurant component like so:

```
@connect((state, props) => {
    return {
        restaurants: state.restaurant.restaurants.find((restaurant) => {
          return restaurant.rid == props.routeParams.rid
        }),
    }
})
```

---

As [@Sean Kwon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3938413/sean-kwon) commented, you should also normalize your data which would make this selector trivial:

```
@connect((state, props) => {
    return {
        restaurants: state.restaurant.restaurants[props.routeParams.rid],
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have connected your action via `mapDispatchToProps`, you organize your store and async actions so that this can be possible.

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchRestaurant(this.props.params.rid)
  }
```

The store will then update your component with the corresponding restaurant data. This way, you're calling some kind of action to get the corresponding data whilst reducing the need to use the component state, which you should try to avoid in order to keep your state centralized.

Otherwise, for a quick and dirty solution, you can just do this really quickly.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var name = this.props.restaurant.find(res => res.rid === nextProps.routeParams.rid)
    this.setState({name: name})
}
```